what should I give instead of 'any' while defining the custom styles for react-select?
enter image description here
I have such a file where I have defined the custom CSS styles for my react-select select component and it works perfectly, but the any in the parameter definition is giving me liniting warning.
what can i give instead of any over there to fix it.
I tried to give some types following some blogs and all, but it ruined my code.

If you means CSS rules, CSSProperty is for that.
See TS tests for React 18
